# API fails to authorize against identity server after successful login over HTTPS

Tags: https, identityserver4, .net-core-2.1

We have an application that is installed on a clients machine. There is 1 website, 10 API's and the identityServer. Users can log in but the process fails when the web tries to load. The API logs are as follows

```
**System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://***.****.com:8091/.well-known/openid-configuration'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://***********:8091/.well-known/openid-configuration'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacketAsync(Stream transport, AsyncProtocolRequest request)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__47_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()**
```

The application is installed on IIS under 12 websites. Each website shares the same internal URL but with different ports. We can get the identity server configuration by browsing to the url but the APIs cannot seem to do the same.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: "The SSL connection could not be established" a cert problem maybe?

Comment: @PabloRecalde yeah. Unfortunately we are trying to use a self signed cert. not a CA. WE have tried to set the domain name in the cert, in the certificate management but it keeps failing. Its pretty frustrating. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is HTTPS issue as mentioned in comments as well.

You need to create 2 certificates to fix this. One for SSL and the other for signing. Use the SSL certificate to set up SSL on your local IIS. Although the SSL certificate won’t be trusted until you configure the cert as trusted on the client machine.

To create these self-signed certificates you can use [`makecert` scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/makecert). All parameters to create these two certificates should match except the CN (common name) parameter. For the SSL cert this must match the host name. For signing it’s just a unique name.

You can read more [here](https://brockallen.com/2015/06/01/makecert-and-creating-ssl-or-signing-certificates/) and [here](https://damienbod.com/2014/04/16/iis-https-configuration-for-team-development/)

Comment: Hey, Thanks so much for the response. I really appreciate it. 
So I followed your guidelines but I am still getting a failure when the API's authorise against the identity server. :(

Comment: Hey, so we found the issue. We had 2 certificates by mistake and the incorrect certificate was bound to the troublesome API's. Once we bound the trusted certificate in it all worked. Thanks you for your help.

Comment: cool! np! plz mark the solution, other people would know it works @JoeyEmp